# Unable to install this application because an application with the same identity is already installed

Tags: click

The old developer created a test certificate and deployed code to server. now he left the company and now i do not know the password for his certificate. so i created another  certificate and tried to deploy on production server and i  get below error. can one one help me?

Activation of http://abc.asd.com/sample.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
Unable to install this application because an application with the same identity is already installed. To install this application, either modify the manifest version for this application or uninstall the preexisting application.

> COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY   No transaction error was
>   detected.
>
> WARNINGS  There were no warnings during this operation.
>
> OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS Activation of
>   http://abc.asd.com/sample.application has started.
>
> ERROR DETAILS     Following errors were detected during this operation.
>     * [3/18/2014 10:21:16 PM]
>   System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentException (Subscription)
>         - Unable to install this application because an application with the same identity is already installed. To install this application,
>   either modify the manifest version for this application or uninstall
>   the preexisting application.
>         - Source: System.Deployment
>         - Stack trace:

```
    at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.CheckApplicationPayload(CommitApplicationParams commitParams)
    at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.CommitApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, CommitApplicationParams commitParams)
    at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
    at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
    at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
```

> COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS   No transaction information is
>   available.

Answer (score 0):

Change the version number and deploy again.
This should fix it.